# Facing an issue with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I am working on an application in which I implement a checkbox in index action of employee controller. It is working fine updating column of the database according to requirement but checkbox changed after pressing CTRL + f5. The code is below

```
<input data-remote="true"
     data-url="<%= active_employee_path(employee.id) %>"
     type="checkbox"
     name="employee"
     <%= "checked" if employee.status == 'Active' %>
/>
```

Please guide me. How to show checkbox according to updated status with out pressing ctrl+F5?

Comment: Are you updating the form through ajax?

Comment: Yes i am updating my account through ajax

Comment: After updating through ajax just redireect it to another controller like /editcontroller?id=